# Creating and rearranging a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python! I have created a code which successfully opens my text file and sorts my list of 100's of words. I then have put these in a list labelled `stimuli_words`, which consists of no duplicates words, all lower case etc.

However I now want to convert this list into a dictionary, where the keys are all possible 3 letter endings in my list of words, and the values are the words that correspond to those endings.

For instance 'ing: going, hiring...', but I only want the words in which have more than 40 words corresponding to the last two characters. So far I have this code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
fq = defaultdict( int )
for w in stimuli_list:
    fq[w] += 1
print fq
```

However it is just returning a dictionary with my words and how many times they occur which is obviously once. e.g  'going': 1, 'hiring': 1, 'driving': 1.

Really would appreciate some help!! Thank You!!

Comment: tried `fq[w[:-3]] += 1` to create a "ing" key.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. In python indentation is very relevant!

Comment: Also please post a source value list and the expected result you would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
dictionary = {}
words = ['going', 'hiring', 'driving', 'letter', 'better', ...] # your list or words

# Creating words dictionary
for word in words:
    dictionary.setdefault(word[-3:], []).append(word)

# Removing lists that contain less than 40 words:
for key, value in dictionary.copy().items():
    if len(value) < 40:
        del dictionary[key]

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{ # Only lists that are longer than 40 words
    'ing': ['going', 'hiring', 'driving', ...],
    'ter': ['letter', 'better', ...],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! however I need to only have in the dictionary the last three characters that have 40 or more words this seems to just print out them all?

Comment: Updated answer to include this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're counting the words (because your key is the word), you only get 1 count per word.

You could create a key of the 3 last characters (and use `Counter` instead):

```
import collections

wordlist = ["driving","hunting","fishing","drive","a"]

endings = collections.Counter(x[-3:] for x in wordlist)

print(endings)
```

result:

```
Counter({'ing': 3, 'a': 1, 'ive': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create DemoData:

```
import random 

# seed the same for any run
random.seed(10)

# base lists for demo data
prae = ["help","read","muck","truck","sleep"]
post= ["ing", "biothign", "press"]

# lots of data
parts = [ x+str(y)+z for x in prae for z in post for y in range(100,1000,100)]

# shuffle and take on ever 15th
random.shuffle(parts) 
stimuli_list = parts[::120]
```

**Creation of dictionary from `stimuli_list`**

```
# create key with empty lists
dic = dict(("".join(e[len(e)-3:]),[]) for e in stimuli_list)

# process data and if fitting, fill list
for d in dic:
    fitting = [x for x in parts if x.endswith(d)]   # adapt to only fit 2 last chars

    if len(fitting) > 5:                            # adapt this to have at least n in it
        dic[d] = fitting[:]

for d in [x for x in dic if not dic[x]]: # remove keys with empty lists
    dic.remove(d)

print()    
print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'ess': ['help400press', 'sleep100press', 'sleep600press', 'help100press', 'muck400press', 'muck900press', 'muck500press', 'help800press', 'muck100press', 'read300press', 'sleep400press', 'muck800press', 'read600press', 'help200press', 'truck600press', 'truck300press', 'read700press', 'help900press', 'truck400press', 'sleep200press', 'read500press', 'help600press', 'truck900press', 'truck800press', 'muck200press', 'truck100press', 'sleep700press', 'sleep500press', 'sleep900press', 'truck200press', 'help700press', 'muck300press', 'sleep800press', 'muck700press', 'sleep300press', 'help500press', 'truck700press', 'read400press', 'read100press', 'muck600press', 'read900press', 'read200press', 'help300press', 'truck500press', 'read800press']
, 'ign': ['truck200biothign', 'muck500biothign', 'help800biothign', 'muck700biothign', 'help600biothign', 'truck300biothign', 'read200biothign', 'help500biothign', 'read900biothign', 'read700biothign', 'truck400biothign', 'help300biothign', 'read400biothign', 'truck500biothign', 'read800biothign', 'help700biothign', 'help400biothign', 'sleep600biothign', 'sleep500biothign', 'muck300biothign', 'truck700biothign', 'help200biothign', 'sleep300biothign', 'muck100biothign', 'sleep800biothign', 'muck200biothign', 'sleep400biothign', 'truck100biothign', 'muck800biothign', 'read500biothign', 'truck900biothign', 'muck600biothign', 'truck800biothign', 'sleep100biothign', 'read300biothign', 'read100biothign', 'help900biothign', 'truck600biothign', 'help100biothign', 'read600biothign', 'muck400biothign', 'muck900biothign', 'sleep900biothign', 'sleep200biothign', 'sleep700biothign']
}
```